# Is there a laser in which based on Ytterbium

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, laser, frequency, cold-atoms

I understand that Ytterbium can emit a photon with a relatively high and very accurate frequency (narrow band of frequency). I also know that Ytterbium is being used to verify frequency in atomic watches (a photon with the right frequency can be absorbed, so if the frequency is shifted than the the light will be reflected). So i wondered if there is a laser that use Ytterbium in the gain medium as an emitter. I didn`t find something like that so my question is: Is such laser exist? if not then why?

Comment: Googling for 'ytterbium laser' has relevant results, so indeed there are.

Comment: It's a well-known laser medium. See [RP-Photonics](https://www.rp-photonics.com/ytterbium_doped_gain_media.html) for more details.

Comment: One problem you tend to run into with such laser is there is no easy way to pump it as ytterbium has only one excited f state. Or rather there wasn't - now we use laser diodes. It's mainly used because you can get nice high quality beam with good spectral quality out of it. You pump it at say 940nm or so, and lasing occurs around 1030 nm. Depends on material. Stokes shift is relatively small, so losses are acceptable. Main takeaway is you can change medium quality laser diode radiation (multimode and quite divergent) into very nice clean beam, and at a relatively high efficiency.

Comment: Thank you all, I see that there is such lasers, but not for the use of very precise  high frequency lasing for the use of a watch. so it is being used to verify frequency in atomic watches, but not to actually produce the light. so i guess that ytterbium laser`s emission, is not as accurate.